# ServerContext.Current is null

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I am facing strange issue.

I have wep-part that reads data from user's profile. Everything is fine than I use short server name say **http://server** but I keep *ServerContext.Current* returning *null* then I access the same page with fully qualified server name say **http://server.zone.local** where *zone.local* is DNS suffix of the zone.

Did anyone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And again I found solution myself.

I just mapped fully qualified URL **http://server.zone.local** to **http://server** in *Central Administration* > *Operations* > *Alternate Access Mappings* and everything works as expected.